# Property determining if content is scrollable (not if it's enabled)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a little animation that shows that a view is scrollable, similar to how `flashScrollIndicators` works for `UIScrollView`. Notice that `flashScrollIndicators` only executes if the view can be scrolled, that is, there is more content to show that doesn't fit in the current view-- how can I get at this property? Like `flashScrollIndicators` I only want my animation to play if the content is scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scroll view is vertically scrollable when its `contentSize.height > bounds.height` and horizontally scrollable when its `contentSize.width > bounds.width`